# dummy output while the card is dislayed in paCMD

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am having a problem with my dummy output.

The output of paCMD `list-sinks` was:

```
$list-sinks   
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB,   front-right: 99957 / 153% / 11.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 4 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 12
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

The output of paCMD `list-cards` was:

```
$list-cards
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.platform-bytcht_es8316>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "bytcht-es8316"
        alsa.long_card_name = "WS-STORMBOOKSB1401-WS001-STORMBOOKSB1401"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_sst_byt_cht_es8316"
        device.bus_path = "platform-bytcht_es8316"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/808622A8:00/bytcht_es8316/sound/card0"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
    profiles:
        input:analog-mono: Analog Mono Input (priority 2, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <input:analog-mono>
    sources:
        alsa_input.platform-bytcht_es8316.analog-mono/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Mono
    ports:
        analog-input: Analog Input (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
```

...However alsa sees it:

```
$aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: bytchtes8316 [bytcht-es8316], device 0: 3 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: bytchtes8316 [bytcht-es8316], device 1: Deep-Buffer Audio (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: what is the context? Audio? what is the issue? what are you trying to do? what is not happening? there are too few words in your question.

Comment: bro the audio is not working

Comment: i am also not able to see any sinks in the pacms list-sinks options

Comment: the only one displayed is the dummy output

Comment: i had been in windows and the audio worked absolutely fine there

Comment: then maybe formulate all of that as part of your title and question. we couldn't possible figure this out from "COMMAND" - "OUTPUT" - "COMMAND" - "OUPUT" - "help me!!".... are we supposed to guess all of this?